# Generics; Type argument is not within its bounds

Tags: kotlin, generics

I've been experimenting with generics lately and found a good instance where I could use them, however, I've become stuck and my searches haven't resulted in a solution, or I've misunderstood. See below code sample:

```
open class X()
class Y : X()
class Z : X()

abstract class A<T : X> {
    lateinit var one: T

    fun setup(
        one: T
    ) {
        this.one = one
    }
}

class B<T : Y> : A<T>()

class C {

    fun initB() {
        B<Y>() // Works as intended
        B<Z>() // Type argument is not within its bounds
        B<X>() // Type argument is not within its bounds
    }

}
```

I would like to have a situation whereby accessing `one` from `class B` type of `one` is correctly inferred, so if I instantiate `B` with type `Z` then `one` will be inferred also as type `Z`. Unfortunately doing this how I thought was the correct way results in '`Type argument is not within its bounds`'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue. `B<T : Y>` specifies that `T` must be a subtype of `Y` and neither `X` nor `Z` are.

Comment: Did you simply mean `class B<T : X> : A<T>()`? Note `X` instead of `Y`. I think that would fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B's type has to be a subtype of Y as you defined it `B<T : Y>`, but neither X nor Z is a subtype of Y. X is a supertype of Y, and Z has no vertical connection to Y at all.

Even if they were subtypes, you couldn't do what you were hoping to. Since your class has a `T` var, `T` has to be invariant for it to work. Invariant means you cannot implicitly up- and down-cast the type of an instance of the class.

Consider how it would break if it allowed you to:

```
val bY: B<Y> = B<Y>()
val bX: B<X> = bY // not allowed because of invariance

// If it were allowed:
bX.one = X()
val y: Y = bY.one // ClassCastException: cannot cast X to Y
```